# Windows Phone 8 Logging

Tags: c#, windows, logging, windows-phone-8

#### Description

I just start Windows Phone Development and I try to put some Logs in my application as I usually do in Android, I try to search through the Internet, but can't find anything useful.

#### Question

Is there in some native methods like Log.i(), Log.e() etc. in Android but for Windows Phone? I don't need to install some new libraries or something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where did you expect to see the Log output?

You can try to use [Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for example :

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Print something");
```

to print some value to Visual Studio output window.